# What is going on in computer memory here?

Tags: c++

So my professor told my class to run this program, it supposedly shows what's going on in computer memory. When I ran it, my output file had the same numbers as my professor's output file for the first like 4 lines and then totally different numbers from then on. But this certainly doesn't seem like it's pulling random numbers, because a lot of the output is 0s and a lot of it are large numbers of similar lengths. Can anyone explain this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>  // for files
#include <cstdlib>   // for exit
#include <climits> // for INT_MAX etc.
int main( )
{
using namespace std;

ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("Whats_in_computer_memory.txt");

cout << "In this program, we declare a small array and then use array syntax " << endl
     << "to see what is in the computer's memory. " << endl
     << " " << endl
     << " " << endl
     << " " << endl
     << " " << endl
     << " " << endl;

int a[1];

int histogram[214749];

for (int i = 0; i < 214749; i++ )
{
    histogram[i] = 0;
}
cout << "&a[0] = " << &a[0] << endl
     << "&histogram[0] = " << &histogram[0]<< endl
     << " " << endl;

cout << INT_MAX << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
{
    outfile << a[i] << endl;
    //cout << INT_MAX/1000000 +a[i]/1000000 << endl;
    //histogram[  a[i]/1000000 ]++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++ )
{
    cout << histogram[ i ] << endl;
}


char dummy;

cin >> dummy;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: what is the output of the program?

Comment: What did you expect to see? You're reading way past the bounds of an array. The program could be showing you anything. Is it one of those professors who try to show you "how powerful C++ is" by using things that are explicitly illegal but look cool?

Comment: Your professor likes undefined behavior?

Comment: This seems like a useless exercise. What point is your professor trying to make?

Comment: If I were your parent, I'd file a complaint with the faculty on the ground of total incompetence of your educator.

Comment: I didn't ask for criticism, I asked why things are the way they are. I understand that the program pulls things from a garbage can of computer memory, but I want to know why it outputs the way it does. Run it for yourselves and avoid wasting your breath by bashing my professor.

Comment: @awallace04 The existing answers have explained perfectly why it outputs what it does. If they haven't covered you, please phrase your question with more details and we can retry.

Comment: @awallace04 If the more specific question is "Why does the gibberish output look structured?", then we can consider that the bit of memory that you're looking at was probably used by some other program in the past to store some data. Generally, data will have some structure to it. Maybe you get long runs of 0s because whatever was using that area of memory earlier zero-d out a block and never got around to using it? It'd be hard to tell for sure without knowing every memory allocation that has ever happened to the machine, however.

Comment: @awallace04 Do note; however, that you'll get different output on different machines, and even the same machine as time goes on (if you run it a lot in quick succession, the Operating System will probably re-allocate the same bit of memory for your program to live in. After all: that was the best block last time, and if nothing has changed then it probably still is)

Answer (score 10):

`a` has one element.  That means

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
{
    outfile << a[i] << endl;
    //cout << INT_MAX/1000000 +a[i]/1000000 << endl;
    //histogram[  a[i]/1000000 ]++;
}
```

is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as soon as `i >= 1`.  Once you have undefined behavior anything can happen so we can no longer reason out what is going on.

Comment: Much better now :)

Answer (score 7):

Your professor is trying to demonstrate that the area of memory around your program contains "stuff" - specifically that the memory around your program isn't zero'd or set to any other default value.

Presumably, this is part of a further point that accessing memory out-of-bounds doesn't guarantee that you'll have any particular value, and as such need to initialise your variables accordingly.

**However;** the problem is that we consider "accessing out-of-bounds of an array" to be undefined behaviour. Undefined behaviour in the C++ standard means "the compiler can handle this situation in whatever way it considers appropriate". Most compilers will serve you values from nearby memory locations (this being simple to do), but they're not required to do so.

Likewise, some compilers can aggressively optimise-out undefined behaviour (like concluding that `i` can never be greater than 1 when used to index into `a`, and adjusting the loop appropriately): compilers are free to assume (for optimisation purposes) that undefined behaviour is never invoked by the programmer. See [this page from the LLVM project](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) for more details on undefined behaviour (noting that under "Dereferences of Wild Pointers and Out of Bounds Array Accesses", both the Clang team and g++ have made the same decision with regards to handling out-of-bounds errors: they access nearby memory locations; because it's the simplest thing to do in that case).